# 3 point draw a Parabola

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
    \begin{axis}[
                 xmin=-0.02,xmax=0.12,
                 ymin=-2,ymax=15,legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}}, 
        legend image post style={mark=*}, xlabel=$Axialrichtung (mm)$,ylabel=$Spannung (MPa)$]
    \addplot[only marks,mark=*,blue] table{O-ring2-N-0.2.txt};

     \draw[red] (axis cs: -0.02, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 11.045);
     \draw[red](axis cs: 0,11.045) parabola bend ( axis cs: 0.1,0) (axis cs: 0,-11.045) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

It should be one parabola open to left, not two*0.5 parabolas open to up and down.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to this site! You need to rotate the parabola, the standard construction is only for "upright" parabolae. Please also provide complete codes. Further information can be found in the comments in the following (complete) code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}%<- it would be better to use the latest version
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[scale=1.6,%<- put scale into the axis options
                 xmin=-0.02,xmax=0.12,
                 ymin=-2,ymax=15,legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}}, 
        legend image post style={mark=*}, xlabel={Axialrichtung (mm)},
        ylabel={Spannung (MPa)}]%<- removed math mode
    %others do not have your data files 
    %\addplot[only marks,mark=*,blue] table{O-ring2-N-0.2.txt};
     \draw[red] (axis cs: -0.02, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 11.045);
    %define symbolic coordinates (don't get transformed) 
     \path (axis cs: 0,11.045) coordinate (tmp1)
      (axis cs: 0.1,0) coordinate (tmp2) (axis cs: 0,-11.045) coordinate (tmp3);
    %draw *rotated* parabola
     \draw[red,rotate=90] (tmp1) parabola bend (tmp2) (tmp3) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!